# Calling setns from Go returns EINVAL for mnt namespace

Tags: c, linux, go, system-calls, cgo

The C code works fine and correctly enters the namespace, but the Go code always seems to return EINVAL from the `setns` call to enter the `mnt` namespace. I've tried a number of permutations (including embedded C code with cgo and external `.so`) on Go `1.2`, `1.3` and the current tip.

Stepping through the code in `gdb` shows that both sequences are calling `setns` in `libc` the exact same way (or so it appears to me).

I have boiled what seems to be the issue down to the code below. What am I doing wrong?

### Setup

I have a shell alias for starting quick busybox containers:

```
alias startbb='docker inspect --format "{{ .State.Pid }}" $(docker run -d busybox sleep 1000000)'
```

After running this, `startbb` will start a container and output it's PID.

`lxc-checkconfig` outputs:

```
Found kernel config file /boot/config-3.8.0-44-generic
--- Namespaces ---
Namespaces: enabled
Utsname namespace: enabled
Ipc namespace: enabled
Pid namespace: enabled
User namespace: missing
Network namespace: enabled
Multiple /dev/pts instances: enabled

--- Control groups ---
Cgroup: enabled
Cgroup clone_children flag: enabled
Cgroup device: enabled
Cgroup sched: enabled
Cgroup cpu account: enabled
Cgroup memory controller: missing
Cgroup cpuset: enabled

--- Misc ---
Veth pair device: enabled
Macvlan: enabled
Vlan: enabled
File capabilities: enabled
```

`uname -a` produces:

```
Linux gecko 3.8.0-44-generic #66~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 04:01:04 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### Working C code

The following C code works fine:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i;
    char nspath[1024];
    char *namespaces[] = { "ipc", "uts", "net", "pid", "mnt" };

    if (geteuid()) { fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "abort: you want to run this as root"); exit(1); }

    if (argc != 2) { fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "abort: you must provide a PID as the sole argument"); exit(2); }

    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        sprintf(nspath, "/proc/%s/ns/%s", argv[1], namespaces[i]);
        int fd = open(nspath, O_RDONLY);

        if (setns(fd, 0) == -1) { 
            fprintf(stderr, "setns on %s namespace failed: %s\n", namespaces[i], strerror(errno));
        } else {
            fprintf(stdout, "setns on %s namespace succeeded\n", namespaces[i]);
        }

        close(fd);
    }
}
```

After compiling with `gcc -o checkns checkns.c`, the output of `sudo ./checkns <PID>` is:

```
setns on ipc namespace succeeded
setns on uts namespace succeeded
setns on net namespace succeeded
setns on pid namespace succeeded
setns on mnt namespace succeeded
```

### Failing Go code

Conversely, the following Go code (which should be identical) doesn't work quite as well:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    if syscall.Geteuid() != 0 {
        fmt.Println("abort: you want to run this as root")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    if len(os.Args) != 2 {
        fmt.Println("abort: you must provide a PID as the sole argument")
        os.Exit(2)
    }

    namespaces := []string{"ipc", "uts", "net", "pid", "mnt"}

    for i := range namespaces {
        fd, _ := syscall.Open(filepath.Join("/proc", os.Args[1], "ns", namespaces[i]), syscall.O_RDONLY, 0644)
        err, _, msg := syscall.RawSyscall(308, uintptr(fd), 0, 0) // 308 == setns

        if err != 0 {
            fmt.Println("setns on", namespaces[i], "namespace failed:", msg)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("setns on", namespaces[i], "namespace succeeded")
        }

    }
}
```

Instead, running `sudo go run main.go <PID>` produces:

```
setns on ipc namespace succeeded
setns on uts namespace succeeded
setns on net namespace succeeded
setns on pid namespace succeeded
setns on mnt namespace failed: invalid argument
```

Comment: Did you try [runtime.LockOsThread](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#LockOSThread)?

Comment: Adding it at the beginning of the goroutine (main) has no effect. That should be sufficient, no?

Comment: The answer on the Go issue is interesting; I'd upvote if you crossposted here @IainLowe

Comment: @twotwotwo I wrote up the answer here as I understand it; let me know if it needs clarification.

Answer (score 8):

(There is [an issue filed on the Go project](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=8676))

So, the answer to this question is that you have to call `setns` from a single-threaded context. This makes sense since `setns` should join the current thread to the namespace. Since Go is multi-threaded, you need to make the `setns` call before the Go runtime threads start.

I *think* this is because the thread in which the call to `syscall.RawSyscall` executes is not the main thread -- even *with* `runtime.LockOSThread` the result is not what you would expect (ie. that the goroutine is "locked" to the main C thread and therefore equivalent to the constructor trick explained below).

The reply I got after filing the issue suggested using "the `cgo` constructor trick". I couldn't find any "proper" documentation on this "trick", but it is used in `nsinit` by Docker/Michael Crosby and even though I went over that code line by line, I didn't try running it this way (see below for frustration).

The "trick" is basically that you can get `cgo` to execute a C function prior to starting the Go runtime.

To do this, you add the `__attribute__((constructor))` macro to decorate the function you want to run before Go starts up:

```
/*
__attribute__((constructor)) void init() {
    // this code will execute before Go starts up
    // in runs in a single-threaded C context
    // before Go's threads start running
}
*/
import "C"
```

Using this as a template, I modified `checkns.go` like this:

```
/*
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

__attribute__((constructor)) void enter_namespace(void) {
   setns(open("/proc/<PID>/ns/mnt", O_RDONLY, 0644), 0);
}
*/
import "C"

... rest of file is unchanged ...
```

This code works, but requires the `PID` to be hardcoded since it's not being read properly from the commandline input, but it illustrates the idea (and works if you provide a `PID` from a container started as described above).

It's frustrating because I wanted call `setns` multiple times but since this C code executes before the Go runtime starts, there is no Go code available.

**Update:** Shlepping around in the kernel mailing lists provides [this link](https://lists.linux-foundation.org/pipermail/containers/2013-January/031565.html) to a conversation that documents this. I can't seem to find it in any actually published manpages, but here's the quote from a patch to `setns(2)`, confirmed by Eric Biederman:

> A process may not be reassociated with a new mount namespace if
>   it  is  multi-threaded. Changing the mount namespace requires
>   that the caller possess both CAP_SYS_CHROOT and CAP_SYS_ADMIN
>   capabilities in its own user namespace and CAP_SYS_ADMIN in the
>   target mount namespace.

Comment: https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/tree/master/libcontainer/nsenter - Contains a working solution base on the init() function solution