# Golang | unix.setns(FD,CLONE_NEWNS) failed with 'invalid argument'

Tags: go, unix, namespaces, containers

I'm trying to use 'unix.setns' to switch the mount namespace from container to host machine like what 'nsenter' command did.
My code is below

```
const (
   CLONE_NEWNS   = 0x20000      /* New mount namespace */
)
nsMNTFD, err := unix.Open("/proc/1/ns/mnt", unix.O_RDONLY|unix.O_CLOEXEC, 0) 
err = unix.Setns(nsMNTFD, CLONE_NEWNS)
```

but it always reported 'invalid argument'. Other namespace like net/ipd works fine. Any idea for how to resolve this error or debug further? thanks in advance!

Comment: does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704661/calling-setns-from-go-returns-einval-for-mnt-namespace

Comment: thx. tried the same but failed either...